# How to track the current line of code executed by another process in C#

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it is possible to get the number of the line of code which is currently executed by another process (within the same program) in c#. Say we have a class "TestClass" which starts two processes: Process A and B. Process A executes a bunch of code while Process B looks from time to time at what line of code process A is. Or it could be the other way round: Process A tells process B at every finished line of code that it just executed that line.

In the end I would like to be able to log a timestamp + the current line of code being executed to a textfile.

Obviously I could have a million Console.WriteLine("Line x");'s in my code, but I would like my application to be more flexible with regard to code changes.

I would appreciate any hint to a library / API that is capable of doing such a thing. Code snippets are also highly appreciated. :)

Best wishes,
Christian

Comment: Have you seen log4net? http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

Comment: That looks very interesting, I will see if it provides what I need. Thank you!

Comment: @Gabe/Christian: A log4net solution would be equivalent to "a million Console.WriteLine"s (albeit a little more flexible), wouldn't it?

Comment: @Scott: log4net can automatically log the line number (`Console.WriteLine` can't) and he can configure it so that the logging of Process A goes directly to Process B (say, via a socket).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to describe your goal more fully, as your intent drives this answer.

If your goal is doing performance analysis (my guess), figuring out what parts of your system are slow, check out tools like JetBrains DotTrace.  If you use any homebrew method in the way you describe, you'll modify/destroy the performance you're trying to analyze.

If your goal is a state monitor (like whether your program is in one state or another) you'll want to build some kind of system so that it will record its current state in a very controlled way, rather than just dumping every line # as you reach it (so I doubt this is your goal).

If your goal is debugging, the VS debugger is your tool of choice.

If you want to trace your system flow, then logging (like the commenter's log4net) is what you should look at.

Comment: Well my purpose is some thing like "tracing the system flow": eventually I would like to log every single line of code being executed. And at the same time, I have recorded a Video: I will then map the video with the lines of code so that after the whole program (process) has finished one can watch the video and see each line of code mapped to the current video frame. Is Log4Net the right choice then?

Comment: @Christian: Like, for the purposes of making a programming tutorial?  Log4NET, in short, will effectively do the same thing as the Console.WriteLine, but with a few more features (like the timestamping you'd need), so, yes and no. I think your best bet is to post another SO question that simply outlines the larger goal you're describing and see what kind of ideas/solutions you get.

Comment: Well not for the purpose of a programming tutorial. Ultimately this video will be used for analysing automated UI tests, since they are under some circumstances not possible to debug. So I would like to use this to run an automated ui test and afterwards see (in case of an exception occuring) why and where this exception occured and what exactly happened. Anyway, thanks for your answer and maybe Log4Net is the right thing to use.

Answer (score 0):

What is the motivation behind doing this? If you just want to understand about the call graph and how long it takes to execute a particular line, wouldn't running your code on a runtime profiler be sufficient?